# How to store data with django redis

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I am using celery and redis in my django project.

```
# In tasks.py
@shared_task
def my_func():
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    context = {
        "my_var1" : afunction(6)
        "my_var2" : afunction(10)
    }
    r.set('this_var', context)

# In views.py
def home(request):
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    return render(request, "home.html", r.get('this_var'))

#In home.html
<h1>{{ my_var1 }}</h1>
<h1>{{ my_var2 }}</h1>
```

where `afunction()` is just a function that I made that does something when taking a number as a parameter.  Also, I have set up celery beat, celery, and redis just fine as I have tested them with other examples to make sure that they work.  Additionally, I have used `r.get` and `r.set` before with other things and they have worked.  However, on the home.html page I do not see the contents of `my_var1` or `my_var2` which suggests to me that `'this_var'` did not store my dictionary `context`.  Can someone please help me?

Also, if I just place context in my `home(request)` function in views.py every thing works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are calling redis.set() with a dictionary whereas set is designed to work with strings. So what gets added to redis is the string representation of your dictionary.

You need to use [hmset](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.hmset) to to save a dictionary and hgetall to retrieve it. eg:

```
r.hmset('this_var', context)
```

and

```
return render(request, "home.html", r.hgetall('this_var'))
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  I get this error: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value, but thanks.

Comment: It definitely does work. Open the python console type those commands into it and see for yourself. The WrongType operation error is because your hmgetall() call is trying to retrieve the value that already exists in redis but tht was inserted in your previous attempt with set() and not hmset() delete that first